# Simple tests for presence of CO₂

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, home-experiment, carbon-family

Am aware that one method for testing for the presence of $\ce{CO2}$ is passing the gas through limewater, with it going cloudy if positive.

Are there any other convenient methods?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SldWCgRasNM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not many simple tests. One of possible tests would be passing gas through neutral solution of suitable acidobasic colour indicator, e.g bromthymol blue, turning green to yellow while getting slightly acidic.

But it would not be specific, any acidic gas would do that.

You have not mentioned context, why do you need to know ? Or is it just homework-like question ?

Comment: I wanted to test a bottle of argon gas. Some unscrupulous sellers mix CO2 in them. I just wanted to compare methods

Comment: Another, not as simple method, would be IR spectroscopy.